# save the jspdf file on the server using js /php and send to mail

Tags: javascript, php

Converted the html data to pdf format using Jspdf.
the file is downloding in the system.but 
The file should be saved on the server

Comment: Please provide more information and some code extracts

Comment: javascript is client side, if you want to save the file on the server, you either have to send the file to the server with an ajax request or save the pdf file on the server side with php